# How to prove the existence of one-sided limits for a non-decreasing function

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ be non-decreasing and $a\in\mathbb R$ is arbitrary. How to show that both of $\lim_{x\to a+}f(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to a-}f(x)$ exist?

Comment: Hint, when a sequence is increasing, the limit is the supremum when it exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** For the limit from the left, let $b$ be the **supremum** of the $f(x)$ over all $x\lt a$. So you need first to show that the set of all $f(x)$ as $x$ ranges over $(-\infty,a)$ is bounded. The existence of the supremum follows immediately, and it is not hard to check, from the definition of supremum, that $b$ is the required limit from the left. The limit from the right is dealt with analogously.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: use the supremum axiom and the fact that:

$\lim_{x \to a-} f(x) = \sup \{ f(x) : x < a \}$

$\lim_{x \to a+} f(x) = \inf \{ f(x) : x > a \}$