# Proving that if the sum of monotonic increasing functions is continuous in a point then each one of them is continuous in the same point.

Tags: calculus, functions, continuity

$g(x)$ and $h(x)$ are monotonic increasing functions s.t the function $(g+h)(x)$ is continuous in $x_0$. prove that $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ are continuous in $x_0.$

here are some thoughts that hit me: I thought that if the sum of both functions is continuous in $x_0$ and we are talking about monotonic functions then the Image $Y$ of values that functions can get is a closed interval. and surely moth functions cover this interval and there is a value $g(x_0)$ and $f(x_0)$ that we get from each function. that means it fulfills the conditions of continuous.

I don't know if my thoughts are in the right direction, I'm open for help from any kind.

Answer (score 3):

A possible approach:

- $f$ and $g$ being monotone [have left and right limits at every point](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/325158/how-to-prove-the-existence-of-one-sided-limits-for-a-non-decreasing-function). Write $m_f = \lim_{x_0^-} f$, $M_f = \lim_{x_0^+} f$, and similarly $m_g, M_g$ for $g$. Moreover, we have $m_f \leq M_f$ (and ditto for $g$) by monotonicity.
- by assumption and operations on limits, $$m_f + m_g = \lim_{x_0^-} (f+g) = \lim_{x_0^+} (f+g) = M_f+M_g$$
- rearranging, $$\underbrace{(M_f - m_f)}_{\geq 0} + \underbrace{(M_g - m_g)}_{\geq 0}  = 0\ .$$ Thus $m_f = M_f$ and $m_g = M_g$, and both $f$ and $g$ are continuous are $x_0$.

Comment: one of the conditions for $g(x)$ or $h(x)$ to be continuous in $x_0$ is that $\lim \limits_{x \to x_0} f(x)$= $f(x_0)$, where did u show that?

Comment: By monotonicity, $m_f \leq f(x_0) \leq M_f$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $(g + h) $ is continuous then for any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta > 0 $ such that for $|x - x_0| <  \delta$ then $|(g+h) (x) - (g+h) (x_0)| \le \epsilon$.

Now split the range of $x$ into $x \ge x_0$ and $x \lt x_0$ and note that with $f$ and $g$ monotonic increasing then so is $(g+h)$ so that

1. for $x \lt x_0$ we have $-\epsilon \le (g+h) (x) - (g+h) (x_0) \le 0$, i.e
   $-\epsilon \le g(x) + h(x) - g(x_0) - h (x_0) \le 0$.  Re-arranging: 
   $-\epsilon \le (g(x)- g(x_0)) + (h(x)  - h (x_0)) \le 0$. Again, with $f$ and $g$ monotonic increasing then $(h(x)  - h (x_0)) \le 0$ = say $-p$ (with $p$ positive), so
   $-\epsilon \le (g(x)- g(x_0)) -p \le 0$ and then
   $-\epsilon \le p-\epsilon \le (g(x)- g(x_0))$ (and \le p$)$, but $ (g(x)- g(x_0)) \lt 0$ because it is monotonic, so $-\epsilon  \le (g(x)- g(x_0)) \le 0$.
   The same argument applies to $h$, $-\epsilon  \le (h(x)- h(x_0)) \le 0$.
2. for $x \ge x_0$ we have $0 \le (g+h) (x) - (g+h) (x_0)  \le \epsilon$ and the same argument gives $0  \le (g(x)- g(x_0)) \le \epsilon$ and gives $0  \le (h(x)- h(x_0)) \le \epsilon$.
3. Putting (1) and (2) back together in modulus form gives for $|x - x_0| <  \delta$ then $|g (x) - g(x_0)| \le \epsilon$ and $|h (x) - h(x_0)| \le \epsilon$, i.e. they are both continuous at $x_0$